# Error in TabLayout code

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Hi I'm new to material design. I'm trying to build a basic tab layout as shown [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/). When I run the app, Studio shows build gradle errors. As the screenshot shows, the error is in the lines `private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();`. I'm unable to understand what the errors are and how to resolve them. So, any help will be much appreciated.

```js
Build Gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.materialtabs"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

```css
layout 

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```html
MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: Added build gradle @Shishram

Comment: change design version from 23.0.1 to 23.1.1 and sync gradle then try if issue persist then post whole stacktrace msg, in screen shot its not completely visible@sam

Comment: Still the same prob after changing design version. full log http://pastebin.com/w2ZnYRB8 @Shishram.

Comment: hmmm, code looks fine but there might be issue with imports so check those in your activity.@sam

Comment: Imports are all good here. @Shishram

Comment: Its seems it problem with JDK 1.6. If you are using java version 1.6 or below version you must have mention generic types. Only java 1.7 and upwards support <> Therefore to support any version you can use.@sam

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726016/hashmap-error-illegal-start-of-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is using JDK 1.6 and you need to switch 1.7 and above, to do that past following object in `defaultConfig` object in `build.gradle(Module:app)` file:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

**EDITED**
goto File>Project Structure and then select JDK home directory.

This should probably solve your problem.

Comment: Still the problem persists after adding compileOptions. I updated the gradle in the post. @chandil03

Comment: check which JDK version is installed in your PC?

Comment: The JAVA_HOME in "Environment" has path of JDK 1.8.0_65 but I've installed both JDK 1.7.0 and JDK 1.8.0_65.

Comment: open cmd and type `java -version` and let me know what it say.

Comment: Its 1.8.0_66 @chandil03

Comment: did you sync your project?

Comment: Yes I synced it. Then tried to run the app. Sync process was success. But while running it showed the error.

Comment: That's how I added "compileOptions". It shows option of 1.6 or 1.7 for both sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility

Comment: i din't understand? did you change your JDK location in project structure?

Comment: I updated the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility in "Project Structure" and Studio automatically added `compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }` in build gradle.

Comment: Hey sam see, you need to change home directory of JDK version for your project. for that got to File> Project Structure and in SDK Location tab you will find setting to change JDK home directory for your project. Change it and you will solve your problem.